# CSS @keyframes not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I was experimenting CSS3 @keyframes animations but I didn't managed to make it work in Chrome (currently I have Chrome 38)

The code is really simple :

**HTML**

```
<div id="block">moving text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes mymove
{
    0%   {top:0px;}
    25%  {top:200px;}
    50%  {top:100px;}
    75%  {top:200px;}
    100% {top:0px;}
}

#block {
    position:absolute;
    animation: mymove 2s infinite;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz7n3/1/) with the same code.

For me the text isn't moving in Chrome 38, but it works great on Firefox 30 and IE 11.

I have tried to use `@-webkit-keyframes` but the text doesn't move either in Chrome.

Comment: It works fine with `-webkit-keyframes` and `-webkit-animation`. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bz7n3/2/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the vendor prefix on both the style property, and keyframes function

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/996Uk/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes mymove /* <--- here */
{
    0%   {top:0px;}
    25%  {top:200px;}
    50%  {top:100px;}
    75%  {top:200px;}
    100% {top:0px;}
}

#block {
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 2s infinite;/* <--- and here */
}
```